# How to free space on the rpi if wolfram etc has already been removed?

Tags: software-installation, swap-space

I already removed wolfram alpha and all the default games that were installed on my rpi.However I still have almost no space left:

[image]

As you can see those are the most voluminous programs on my systems there are 3 others that take +/- 10Mb, but that's it!

[image]

How could I get some extra space on my RPI?

Comment: Do NOT post links to external images. Paste into your question (preferably as TEXT).

Comment: I agree with Jacob's answer.   8 GB is not much space for what is, essentially, a general purpose OS with GUI that's primarily used on computers with much bigger storage.  Raspbian is really [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) repackaged.  *It was not at all created from scratch for use on dev boards with SD cards.*  If you want a minimal headless install, you can do it under 2 GB, but if you want to use it like a laptop **then you need appropriate space for the OS**.  It is also probably a good idea to not fill the card more than 70-80%.  Get a bigger one!

Answer (score 2):

> How could I get some extra space on my RPI?

The clear and obvious answer is **get a bigger SD card**. 8 GB isn't really that large.

Short of migrating:

1. You could look into removing any development packages you're not using.
2. Run the command `sudo apt autoremove` to remove packages that are no longer being used.

Comment: I ran theat command (autoremove), but it didn't remove anything.

Comment: @thubostehu: Then shy of removing development packages (I have no idea which you may have installed), there isn't really a lot for us to go on here.

Comment: Depending on your use for your Raspberry and especially whether you need a graphical user interface, the Raspbian Lite image may be a better starting point for an 8 GB card.